# UI-calendar recurring event on angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have tried to implement the recurring frequency on Angular UI-calendar but still didn't get any angular plugin.I need help in creating recurring event.If you can please give any reference plugin or directive to create recurring event.

I got Ui-calendar from here [calendar downloaded link](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/)

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

I leveraged the fact that, on a view switch of the calendar, the Arshaw calendar can employ an events functions (http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/).

First assemble the array of repeating events in your service into an 7-slot array of arrays, one slot for each day of the week.  Put this on the scope. Then when you open up or switch the calendar view, iterate from the start day to the end day of the function, and insert an event that matches your recurrence type.

```
function eventFunction(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    var events = [];
    for(var date = start; date <= end; date.setTime( date.getTime() + MS_PER_DAY )){
        _.forEach($scope.calendar.repeating[date.getDay()], function(repeater){
            var repeaterStart = date.getTime() +  // date
                repeater.start - new Date(repeater.start).setHours(0,0,0,0);  //  time
            events.push({ _id: repeater.id, start:  new Date(repeaterStart), title: repeater.headline})
        })
    }
    callback(events);
}
```